# postgresSQL universal query

Tags: sql, postgresql, psycopg2

Let's suppose we have two queries (I use postgresSQL with psycopg2):

1 -

```
query= """
SELECT * FROM same_table
"""
```

2 -

```
query= """
SELECT * FROM same_table
WHERE id = %(some_id)s
"""
```

Is it possible to crate a single statement for both situations? To retrieve a specific one row by sending an ID in a variable and to retrieve all rows by sending null, 0, or anything differnt from an integer greater than 0.

A nice solucion would be some kind of if-than structure, but I'm not sure if how this is done in sql.

Comment: @Charlieface There shouldn't be an injection problem if the OP is following [the documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries), but it isn't clear from the code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would probably work:

```
query= """
SELECT * FROM same_table
WHERE case when %(some_id)=0 then true else id = %(some_id)s end
"""
```

Comment: At a cost of probably a non-optimal query plan. The dynamic option is generally much better.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to solve the problem in Python instead of in SQL. A simple approach might look like this:

```py
query = "SELECT * FROM same_table"

if some_id is not None:
    query += " WHERE id = %(some_id)"
```

And if you'd prefer to get away from writing SQL by hand entirely, you can look into tools like [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) or [Peewee](https://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/), which allow you to write code like this:

```py
query = SameTable.select()

if some_id is not None:
    query = query.where(SameTable.id == some_id)

for row in query:
    print(row)
```